# how to build a custom directive for a button-group with AngularJS (link button-group template)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is an interesting question:
I am trying to build a button-group custom directive, so that I would be able to use it as a template. At the moment I have the following (which is too specific and not adjustable:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app1', []);

  app.controller('LinkController', function($scope) {
  $scope.go = function(link) {
  window.location = link;};
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg"data-ng-controller="LinkController">
  <button type="button"class="btn btn-primary"data-ng-click="go('go1.html')">Click1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="go('go2.html')">Click2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="go('go3.html')">Click3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="go('go4.html')">Click4</button>
</div>
```

So basically, each button re-directs to a different page. If I was to use it as a custom directive, it would be to specific and I can't really re-use it. I want to be able to generalize it, so that I can call a directive with four names for four buttons, as well as four links for each. This way, I can regenerate such groups for different pages, and give input of the button names and links as variables that would be taken by a function which will automatically create the required button group.

Any idea how I should go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to put your buttons in an array each button being an object with text and link properties then just use ng-repeat to iterate through it and rather then try and make your own link function just put it inside an anchor tag (<a><\a>)

Comment: @Binvention you are probably right, I should try this.